# How do I sync photos across multiple devices?

Tags: photography, file-management

I'm looking at syncing photos across multiple devices for a client of mine. I'm working for a garden design company, with constant updates of projects from my end.

Is there a way to upload from my mac, so that everyone has access to the files and individual folders and also have the photos available offline in poor Wi-Fi spots. There are multiple iPads and iPhones that need access to this.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your best option would be an online file storage that has computer sync.

What the *sync* does, is it leaves a folder on your computer where you place all the files. Any changes you make will get *synced* across all devices (including people who have the folder shared with them).

---

- [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/)
- [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/)
- [OneDrive](http://onedrive.live.com)

<sub><sup>There are more, these are the big ones.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about just apple devices, I believe you can do a shared album with iCloud. That should sync photos to the devices of those who the album is shared with, so they'd be available offline. Obviously you'd want to test this to be sure it works the way you want it to, but see this article for more information:

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12068?locale=en_US

Otherwise, as the other answer mentions, a syncable solution like Dropbox would work - I know at least the Dropbox app allows a folder to be marked as "available offline," which should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not or will not use cloud services for syncing use:

- [Rsync](https://www.tecmint.com/rsync-local-remote-file-synchronization-commands/), rsync is available for all platforms

or if bi-directional sync is needed and/or for convenience then use

- [Unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/), also available on most platforms.

Synching has been done for decades.